# Where is TIOCMGET supposed to be implemented?

Tags: linux, mono, ioctl

This is really just to satisfy my curiosity after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652370/why-does-serialport-open-fail) question. Although I'm now using an alternative solution, the original problem appears to come down to the fact that TIOCMGET is not implemented, and I'd like to know a bit about why that is.

Sadly, I haven't found much useful information just by googling, and I'm finding the tty_ioctl man page (the first result) pretty impenetrable.

So, what exactly is TIOCMGET, where is it implemented, and where might mono be looking for it and failing to find it?

Comment: The man page implies that it is implemented, at least at the C level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implemented in `drivers/tty/tty_io.c` which has the following implementation:

```
/**
 *      tty_tiocmget            -       get modem status
 *      @tty: tty device
 *      @file: user file pointer
 *      @p: pointer to result
 *
 *      Obtain the modem status bits from the tty driver if the feature
 *      is supported. Return -EINVAL if it is not available.
 *
 *      Locking: none (up to the driver)
 */

static int tty_tiocmget(struct tty_struct *tty, int __user *p)
{
        int retval = -EINVAL;

        if (tty->ops->tiocmget) {
                retval = tty->ops->tiocmget(tty);

                if (retval >= 0)
                        retval = put_user(retval, p);
        }
        return retval;
}
```

As you will note from the comment, and the code, it only works if the underlying terminal driver supports it and will otherwise return `EINVAL`.

There are a number of drivers which do support it, such as `isdn4linux` and various GSM modem drivers, but ordinary terminals won't do as they are not modems.